# Can not display content from database for editing in the form with CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update, codeigniter-3

I am trying for some time to display the values of each column in the fields of the selected row in my editing form. The `update` operation is updating normally, I just need to display it otherwise I either have to write everything all over again or save in blank.

I have my own model called `MY_Model.php`:

```
<?php

class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public $table = '';
    protected $primary_key = 'id';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('inflector');
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array($this->primary_key = $id))->row();
    }

    public function select()
    {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $query->free_result();

        return $data;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        $data['date_created'] = $data['date_updated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['created_from_ip'] = $data['updated_from_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

        if ($this->db->insert($this->table, $data)) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update($data, $id)
    {
        $data['date_updated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['updated_from_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);

        return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);

        return $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->table);
    }
}
```

Then, the `edit` method of my `Customers` controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['address'] = $this->input->post('address');

        $this->Customers_model->update($data, $id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Cliente \'' . $data['name'] . '\' alterado');

        redirect('/admin/customers', 'refresh');
    }

    $data['customer'] = $this->Customers_model->get($id);
    $data['page'] = $this->config->item('admin_template_dir_admin') . 'edit_customers';
    $data['module'] = 'admin';

    $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
}
```

I have tried many things to be able to display the values in the fields while editing the form. The way it is now, if I do a `var_dump($customer)`, shows `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this code

```
<?php

class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public $table = 'table_name';
    protected $primary_key = 'id';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('inflector');
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array($this->primary_key => $id))->row();
    }

    public function select()
    {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $query->free_result();

        return $data;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        $data['date_created'] = $data['date_updated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['created_from_ip'] = $data['updated_from_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

        if ($this->db->insert($this->table, $data)) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update($data, $id)
    {
        $data['date_updated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['updated_from_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);

        return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);

        return $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->table);
    }
}
```

Your controller function

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('MY_Model');
        if ($this->input->post()) {
            $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
            $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
            $data['address'] = $this->input->post('address');

            $this->MY_Model->update($data, $id);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Cliente \'' . $data['name'] . '\' alterado');

            redirect('/admin/customers', 'refresh');
        }

        $data['customer'] = $this->MY_Model->get($id);
        $data['page'] = $this->config->item('admin_template_dir_admin') . 'edit_customers';
        $data['module'] = 'admin';

        $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
    }
```

Comment: It changed something, but I still cannot make the data to be filled. What do I do with my `edit()` method in my controller?

Comment: I could not get your point. As you said you have problem in displaying the customers. And that is done by your get() function so why you need edit function for displaying customers and where you load the model in the controller @mfgabriel92

Comment: I want to fill the edit form fields with the selected register's values from de database.

Comment: I have updated the code please take a look now. Please make the necessary changes as per your requirement,,,@mfgabriel92

Comment: I cannot believe I missed one '>' in the `get()` function. This is working now. Thank you a lot!

Comment: yes you are right u missed ">" in the get(). @mfgabriel92